# How to set a max number of characters in a cell and automatically skip 2 rows when max number of characters is reached in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking for a way to do this in Google Sheets:

Set the maximum count of characters per cell of column D = 70.
If characters count of any cell in column D >= 70, then skip 2 rows.

Explanation:

I want to be able to write text in excel efficiently skipping 2 rows every 70 characters.

Example:

In Google Sheets cell D1, writing short sentences/strings of 70 characters max.
When cell D1 characters count >= 70, having the cursor automatically skip 2 rows (cells D2 and D3).
Continue writing/inputting the rest of the sentence/string from cell D1 directly into cell D4.

Do the same operations automatically from cell D4 to cell D7, from D7 to D10 etc. for all of column D.

Is this possible in Google Sheets without scripting? 
If scripting is necessary, what would be a good way, to begin with?

Here's an additional thread about the question for Excel: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1081011-how-set-max-number-character-cell-automatically-skip-2-rows-when-max-number-character-reached-2.html#post5195931

Comment: you can't force selection of cell to move two cells below without using scripts. if you want formula solution the workflow would need to be like this: you enter stuff in one column and in next column there will be an array formula evaluating the column you type in and automatically do what you request

Comment: Hi player0, thanks for the advice. Does the array formula would make the operation to skip 2 rows on the 2nd column (B) as one types in the 1st cell of column (A)? Would that work like that possibly: One types into cell A1 and it  "transposes" automatically in cell B1. Then, as soon as 70 characters are reached in cell A1/B1, the following characters would appear automatically in cell B4. Then once 140 characters are reached in cell A1, the following characters are automatically transposed into cell B7, and so on? If so what array formula to use?

Comment: Would the character limit in cell A1 limit this solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

### ROBOTIC SOLUTION:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, 
 "(.{70})", "♦$1"&"♀♂♀♂♀"), "♦♀")), "♂", ""))
```

[image: 0]

---

### AI SOLUTION:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 REGEXREPLACE(A1&" ", "[\r\n\s]+", " "), "(\S.{0,70})\s", 
 "$1"&CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦"), "\n+\z", ""), "♦")), CHAR(10), ""))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank a lot player0! It works when copying and pasting text into A1, but I overlooked 3 issues. While typing, the cells width keeps extending to the right end despite text wrap as this https://i.imgur.com/IwDS57K.png . I researched a way to lock the cell width in Google Sheets, but apparently it is only possible in Excel.

Comment: 2nd issue is the row height also keeps going down to eventually cover the whole sheet while typing: https://i.imgur.com/UD3A0Ex.png.

Comment: 3rd issue: one cannot type and follow live the result in column B past the current onscreen number of rows without having to scroll down and go back up to continue typing. If those issues are not easily solvable with a formula, what would you advise about doing it via the app script?

Comment: 1: text wrap works only on inactive cell (as soon as you start typing the overview will kick in and fill the screen - box with a blue border on your picture) after you press enter the overview will disapear and you are left with cell on whych you can apply the text wrap you wish. there is no way to kill overview not even with script

Comment: 2. row height can be set either on floating point or fixed on entered px height. however again... the thing on your 2nd picture is not a cell. its overview of future changes.

Comment: 3: its kinda standard behavior which cant be solved with formulas nor scripts

Comment: Ok, thanks for those answers, it helps a lot to know what is possible! So one can't get around the mandatory click on enter to get out of the overview. But is there a way in google sheets   to automate the "carriage return" and skip 2 rows while typing each time the cell's lenght reaches 70 char? so that one doesn't have to hit enter manually when that happens? An excel script propose a way here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1081011-how-set-max-number-character-cell-automatically-skip-2-rows-when-max-number-character-reached-post5195244.html#post5195244

Comment: Would be great to have a special function in google sheets to turn it into a typewriter with something like this: =IFS(As soon as len(C1)>=70,AND(Split the text past 70 charracters,Skip two rows),len(C1)<70,Do nothing)

Comment: you can do carriage return while typing with ctrl+enter but to automate the whole process while typing and process wished rules upon it is not possible. scripts and formulas are able to work only with output and active cell is not considered as output but rather as input

Comment: Ok thanks for that important info, I didn't know about that limitation. If I may ask a general question. Is it because of the cell structure? Why say, does it work in google docs? that automatically do the carriage return at the end of each line (before the right margin)?

Comment: the structural logic of a spreadsheet is a bit different than of a document. in document, it's expected this to be automated coz of print purposes so it won't happen that you print something and half of the sentences are out of printing area. in a spreadsheet, this is not automated and it's up to individual approach how it will be formatted. there would be an outrage of angry people if this got to be automated as in text document

Comment: Ok thanks for this explanation. It makes sense. But ideally it would be great to have both options in Google sheets. Say, the  option to "block" a column or range of cells to behave like a Google docs automated carriage return, while having all others columns as default non automated Google sheets behavior. It would raise the simpicity of google docs to the power of google sheets! Do you know if combining the two systems would be possible in terms of input output limitation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess best would be for you to use Google Docs and insert a table

Comment: Thanks for the last sugg. I'll try it and see what it does. In the meantime I found something related here (though not a spreadsheet structure per se) https://gingkoapp.com/

Comment: @Tanaike Do you know a possible Apps Script solution to this question? or a formula if the current Google Sheets funcionality permits?